# Where can I get all XBRL tags with descriptions and details

Tags: sec

I'm trying scraping SEC filings using open source xbrl platform  Arelle(arelle.org). Using their docs I have managed scraping from SEC rss and storing them in postgresql database. What I am struggling about is for querying any information about fundamentals item of any company I need knowing the corresponding exact us-gaap XBRL tag like one I've highlighted in the image.
So for example I'm trying querying all items listed on an example site : https://github.com/altova/SECDB/blob/master/docs/DB-SCHEMA.md which is a proprietory software and I dont intend using. So is there any sites available that can help me get all us-gaap xbrl tags with all their corresponding meanings and many names?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Because XBRL is an *extensible* format, there is not an all-encompassing list of tags that can be declared in an XBRL instance. Business entities may create their own unique tags to accommodate special reporting requirements. However, the concepts for the vast majority (+90%) of the facts declared in XBRL instances are defined in the DEI or US-GAAP schema definition files. The most recent versions of these files are at

http://xbrl.sec.gov/dei/2014/dei-2014-01-31.xsd

and

http://xbrl.fasb.org/us-gaap/2016/elts/us-gaap-2016-01-31.xsd

respectively.